# What does the phrase "try filling in" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

Please help me figure out the meaning of the phrase "try filling in" in the following text from the description of the game Genshin Impact:

> You can use earth elemental combat skills to create a “starfall” and
> put it in place of a missing stone statue to unlock a treasure chest.
> You can **try filling in** or destroying other similarly incongruous
> features, such as collectibles, rock piles or monsters, to uncover
> bonuses.

I am not sure which of the lexical meanings given [here](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/fill%20in) fits in the given context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't be sure, but from the description it sounds like they're talking about a game mechanic that allows you to "fill in" spaces, holes etc. (like the example about creating something to fill the empty space left by a missing statue).

The sentence is written in a typical way to describe opposite or contrasting things, like "give and take" - in this case you can "fill in or destroy features", it sounds like it's implying that *filling in* is the opposite of destroying in some sense. Adding instead of removing. It's not very well written though - none of those examples (rocks, collectibles, monsters) sound like something you could "fill in" in any sense!

As far your example meanings go, it's probably meant in the sense of supplying something that's missing or required (like a statue), or taking up space completely (like filling in a hole, so the hole doesn't exist anymore). I can't find any specific information about the game mechanic though, so I'm just assuming by the context!